# GlassFish 3.1.2 HTTP connection slow after some time

Tags: glassfish, threadpool, glassfish-3

I am facing one critical issue. GlassFish 3.1.2(Oracle GlassFish final) server HTTP post methods are working only for first few minutes of GlassFish server restart. After some period of time HTTP connection takes 2 mins to initiate the request to the POST URL.

EDIT (from Comments): Java: jdk1.7 OS: Cent OS 7 64bit

After starting GlassFish server, I can access any URL using HttpUrlConnection. But after few minutes, It takes 2 minutes to initiate a request and get a response

For Example:

```
String msgURL = "someurl";
URL url = new URL(MsgURL); 
HttpsURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
if(null != httpsConn) { 
  System.out.println(httpsConn.getResponseCode()); }
```

If I restart the GlassFish server again, I am able to get response quickly. again after few minutes facing same slowness is sending reques

Can any one help me in this ?

Comment: Is there more information you can add?

Comment: @Will thanks for your reply 
Java: jdk1.7
OS: Cent OS 7 64bit
After starting GlassFish server, I can access any URL using HttpUrlConnection. But after few minutes, It takes 2 minutes to initiate a request and get a response 
For Example,
 String msgURL = "https://someurl";
 URL url = new URL(MsgURL);
 HttpsURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 if(null != httpsConn) {
 System.out.println(httpsConn.getResponseCode());
 }
 
If I restart the GlassFish server again, I am able to get response quickly. again after few minutes facing same slowness is sending reques

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you create always new connections. It may happen that all connections from the connection pool of the glassfish are in use, and you get a new connection after some of the connections times out. The timeout can explain the delay you are facing.